# A conjectured formula related to positive integer sequences generated by coprime numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Conjecture:

> Given $a,b\in\mathbb N_+$ with $\gcd(a,b)=1$ there are no
> $m,n\in\mathbb N\ni 0$ such that $(a-1)(b-1)-1=ma+nb$, but such
> $m,n\in\mathbb N$ exists for all $N\geq(a-1)(b-1)$.

I guess it is possible to construct $m,n\in\mathbb N$ such that
$(a-1)(b-1)=ma+nb$ but I can't see how right now, and that it is possible to proceed by induction, but how to prove that there is no $m,n\in\mathbb N$ such that $(a-1)(b-1)-1=ma+nb$? Thankful for all help!

I was looking for a binary operation $f(a,b)$ as above and noticed that
$f(a,b)=f(b,a)$, $f(1,b)=1$ and $f(2,b)=b$ similar to cancelation and identity for multiplication and tried $f(a,b)=(a-1)(b-1)$ which seems to be correct due to some testing.

Example $a=4, b=9$ where $3\cdot 8=24$:

```
{0,4,8,9,12,13,16,17,18,20,21,22,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,...}
```

---

I could also need some help finding $m,n\in\mathbb N$ such that $(a-1)(b-1)=ma+nb$ and with the induction part.

Comment: I think this has been asked here already : Basically , given coprime positive integers $a,b$ , you ask for the largest non-negative integer $N$ that cannot be expressed as $ma+nb$ with non-negative integers $m,n$.

Comment: @Peter - Exactly! Thanks for the enhancement! Except, I call that number $N-1$.

Comment: I edited my comment : It is the LARGEST such number.

Comment: See [Frobenius Coins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem)

Comment: This well known result (Frobenius Coin Problem) is proved here many times, e.g. see the linked dupe.